# Compare value in data frame to a value in different column in previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with Start and End times in different columns representing periods where a weather warning is in place.

```
 Warning  StartDate         End Date          Warning Issued
   1        01/05/2017 3:40   01/05/2017 4:10   Yes
   2        01/05/2017 4:10   01/05/2017 4:40   Yes
   3        02/05/2017 1:50   02/05/2017 2:30   Yes
   4        02/05/2017 2:35   02/05/2017 3:20   Yes
   5        02/05/2017 3:20   02/05/2017 4:00   Yes
   6        02/05/2017 4:00   02/05/2017 4:30   Yes
   7        03/05/2017 7:05   03/05/2017 7:50   Yes
   8        03/05/2017 7:50   03/05/2017 8:20   Yes
```

For validation purposes I need to round the start and end times to the inclusive half hour (floor start times and ceiling end times) which is easy enough, but where warnings are continuous, this creates overlapping warnings for example warning 1 & 2 would overlap by 30 min:

```
Warning  FloorStartDate       CeilEnd Date      Warning Issued
   1     01/05/2017 3:30      01/05/2017 4:30   Yes
   2     01/05/2017 4:00      01/05/2017 5:00   Yes
```

However if I just round the times, I will lose half hour periods where the warnings are not continuous (e.g. The half hour period '1.30 -2pm' when warning 3 starts would be lost).

I want to find a solution where I can compare the start date in row 2 to the end date in row one, if they are equal then I will round the times, and if they are not I will floor/ceiling the times. The table would look like this:

```
Warning   StartDate         End Date     WarnIss GroomStart     GroomEnd
    1  01/05/2017 3:40   01/05/2017 4:10  Yes 01/05/2017 3:30  01/05/2017 4:00
    2  01/05/2017 4:10   01/05/2017 4:40  Yes 01/05/2017 4:00  01/05/2017 5:00
    3  02/05/2017 1:50   02/05/2017 2:30  Yes 02/05/2017 1:30  02/05/2017 2:30
    4  02/05/2017 2:35   02/05/2017 3:20  Yes 02/05/2017 2:30  02/05/2017 3:30
    5  02/05/2017 3:20   02/05/2017 4:00  Yes 02/05/2017 3:30  02/05/2017 4:00
    6  02/05/2017 4:00   02/05/2017 4:30  Yes 02/05/2017 4:00  02/05/2017 4:30
    7  03/05/2017 7:05   03/05/2017 7:50  Yes 03/05/2017 7:00  03/05/2017 8:00
    8  03/05/2017 7:50   03/05/2017 8:20  Yes 03/05/2017 8:00  03/05/2017 8:30
```

I have searched high and low for any sort of answer and the closest I could get was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446844/fastest-way-to-compare-row-and-previous-row-in-pandas-dataframe-with-millions-of). This code compares the row before it, but only in the same column. I tried to repurpose the code (below) but it will only return the else value (I suspect because I am not iterating correctly or am not locating the values correctly).

Can anyone suggest if this is possible, and if so, point out where my code is failing or provide an alternative solution for me?

```
import pandas as pd

def FormatWarning(inputcsv,outputcsv):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df = pd.read_csv(inputcsv,\
                     index_col=None, \
                     names=['Warning','DateStart','DateEnd',\
                            'WarningIssued'],\
                     sep=',',\)
    df["DateStart"]= pd.to_datetime(df["DateStart"],format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
    df["DateEnd"]= pd.to_datetime(df["DateEnd"],format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')

for i in range(2, len(df)):
    if df.loc[i,'DateStart']== df.loc[i-1,'DateEnd']:
        df["EditDTS"]= df["DateStart"].dt.round('30T')
    else:
        df["EditDTS"]= df["DateStart"].dt.floor('30T')

for i in range(1, len(df)-1):
    if df.loc[i,"DateEnd"]==df.loc[i+1,"DateStart"]:
        df["EditDTE"]=df["DateEnd"].dt.round('30T')
    else:
        df["EditDTE"]=df["DateEnd"].dt.ceil('30T')       
df.to_csv(outputcsv, index=False)
```

Comment: Hi @JojoBambam. In the cases where alerts are continuous, would you still want these to appear as separate lines in your end DF, or would you rather these were merged together into one single time block when a warning was active?

Comment: I would like them to remain separate as they have other attributes associated with them that I have excluded from the code for brevity.

Comment: Thanks - I've left an answer and hope I've understood your request properly. I'm applying a function on row-wise elements but also passing the DF so that the function can also access the previous or following row.

Comment: If this does solve your problem, please can you mark the question as solved? This means that both of our ratings will improve on StackOverflow which helps with future questions / answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've approached it a slightly different way - I'm using `.apply(axis=1)` to access each row individually, but then passing both that row and the master DF to a defined method. Rationale for passing both is that I can access the `.name` property of each row rather than iterating through a loop. Working in vectorised operations like this can be faster, and is more explicit I find.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["1","01/05/2017 3:40","01/05/2017 4:10","Yes"],
        ["2","01/05/2017 4:10","01/05/2017 4:40","Yes"],
        ["3","02/05/2017 1:50","02/05/2017 2:30","Yes"],
        ["4","02/05/2017 2:35","02/05/2017 3:20","Yes"],
        ["5","02/05/2017 3:20","02/05/2017 4:00","Yes"],
        ["6","02/05/2017 4:00","02/05/2017 4:30","Yes"],
        ["7","03/05/2017 7:05","03/05/2017 7:50","Yes"],
        ["8","03/05/2017 7:50","03/05/2017 8:20","Yes"],
    ], columns=["Warning","DateStart","DateEnd","Warning Issued"]
)
df["DateEnd"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateEnd"])
df["DateStart"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateStart"])


def start_process(row, df):
    try:
        if row["DateStart"] == df.loc[(row.name - 1), "DateEnd"]:
            return row["DateStart"].round('30T')
        else:
            return row["DateStart"].floor('30T')
    except KeyError:
        # Either the first or last entry, so just return the original
        return row["DateStart"]

def end_process(row, df):
    try:
        if row["DateEnd"] == df.loc[(row.name + 1), "DateStart"]:
            return row["DateEnd"].round('30T')
        else:
            return row["DateEnd"].ceil('30T') 
    except KeyError:
        # Either the first or last entry, so just return the original
        return row["DateEnd"]

df["EditDTS"] = df.apply(lambda x: start_process(x, df), axis=1)
df["EditDTE"] = df.apply(lambda x: end_process(x, df), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Results in:

```
  Warning           DateStart             DateEnd Warning Issued  \
0       1 2017-01-05 03:40:00 2017-01-05 04:10:00            Yes
1       2 2017-01-05 04:10:00 2017-01-05 04:40:00            Yes
2       3 2017-02-05 01:50:00 2017-02-05 02:30:00            Yes
3       4 2017-02-05 02:35:00 2017-02-05 03:20:00            Yes
4       5 2017-02-05 03:20:00 2017-02-05 04:00:00            Yes
5       6 2017-02-05 04:00:00 2017-02-05 04:30:00            Yes
6       7 2017-03-05 07:05:00 2017-03-05 07:50:00            Yes
7       8 2017-03-05 07:50:00 2017-03-05 08:20:00            Yes

              EditDTS             EditDTE
0 2017-01-05 03:40:00 2017-01-05 04:00:00
1 2017-01-05 04:00:00 2017-01-05 05:00:00
2 2017-02-05 01:30:00 2017-02-05 02:30:00
3 2017-02-05 02:30:00 2017-02-05 03:30:00
4 2017-02-05 03:30:00 2017-02-05 04:00:00
5 2017-02-05 04:00:00 2017-02-05 04:30:00
6 2017-03-05 07:00:00 2017-03-05 08:00:00
7 2017-03-05 08:00:00 2017-03-05 08:20:00
```

*Note: I'm using Pandas 0.22 and Python 3.5, so if any code doesn't work on your setup that might be a cause.*

**Edit 19/01/2018**

To answer the question of why the original code didn't work: I didn't notice the error with the original code at the time because I refactored it into a row-wise method using `.apply()`. However, I now see that your assignment looks like the issue.

With each loop, you're performing an operation on the whole DF column rather than the specific row:

```
for i in range(2, len(df)):
    # Your lookup was correct, using the row indexers...
    if df.loc[i,'DateStart']== df.loc[i-1,'DateEnd']:
        # but the assignment is being made on the whole column,
        # so each iteration is potentially undoing the work of the last iteration.
        df["EditDTS"]= df["DateStart"].dt.round('30T')
    else:
        df["EditDTS"]= df["DateStart"].dt.floor('30T')
```

You would just need to use the same indexers from the `if` statement into the operation below:

```
if df.loc[i,'DateStart']== df.loc[i-1,'DateEnd']:
    df.loc[i, "EditDTS"]= df.loc[i-1, "DateStart"].dt.round('30T')
```

So - the refactor wasn't necessary, but by breaking up the steps it's potentially clearer to debug. (Inspired by [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python))

Comment: Thanks Phil! Works perfectly. Only thing to note is for both exceptions I added the respective floor and ceiling arguments, otherwise they would return the original times.
Also are you able to give me any insight as to why row works but not item?

Comment: @JojoBambam - I will leave an edit to my answer, as it's easier to show code markup there.

Comment: Thank you for that insight! I'm in the early stages of learning python and its these small things that are the hardest (and most frustrating) to pick up and learn from!

Comment: Glad to help @JojoBambam. This method of working on a whole series is a strength of Pandas in particular (ie vector based operations, faster than standard loops), but is initially counter-intuitive to common Python loops. It might be worth reading up specifically on Pandas to grok the best way of working with dataframes. https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1-intro.html is a good series of articles. Good luck!